# How come MIM is getting through outlook SSl security

Tags: tls

Hello I am using outlook with ssl security to connect to a mail server but whenever I launch a MIM attack and accept the fake certificate my password is shown. How is this possible? Shouldn't I be connecting securely with ssl where the attackers wont be able to manipulate the certificate?

And if the certificate of outlook is getting faked by MIM over ssl why cant I fake the Facebook cert as well over ssl and reveal the login info?

Is there different types of certificates stronger? or better?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about security not programming.

Answer (score 2):

> accept the fake certificate

This is the problem. SSL won't protect data against end users who read security alerts about unrecognised certificates and then accept them anyway.

> Is there different types of certificates stronger? or better?

Yes, but that won't help with a MITM gives the user a different certificate and the user accepts it.